# Constant error from Service SyncHost & CDPUserSvc on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-service, zabbix, windows-server-2016

We are are running a couple of Windows Server 2016 boxes for some of our environments to start testing things out but we have been getting constant errors from the two above services not running. Essentially, the above services create themselves as users log in, so when the user logs out the service is left in a stopped state and we can't start it or alert it so our monitoring system continues to alert us about useless errors. All the services do is sync maps, contacts, and e-mail so i'm not sure why they are even included in the Windows Service 2016 image.

I'm curious to see if anyone else has ran into this issue and has possibly found a solution or does everyone just ignore them?

Our monitoring solution is Zabbix, and the reason these services are picked up is because Zabbix scans for all services running on the host machine. I am not aware of any way to make the discovery rules filter out services that start with CDP_ or Service_ in our version of zabbix so i'm just trying to find a good workaround. We are running version 2 of zabbix

[Screenshot of what error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV91o.png)

Comment: How are those items added? Which exact version of Zabbix?

Comment: Currently using version 2.2. They are added by a discovery rule that is linked to that object that essentially just looks at all windows services and reports if they are running or not

Comment: What is "that object"? What's the LLD rule key?

Comment: So "the object" in this case is just one of the Windows Server 2016 that the Zabbix agent is installed on. The LLD applied on that server is a discovery rule that is attached to that server. All the discovery rule does is examine the server the agent is on and retrieve all of the services that are part of that machine.

Comment: ...and the LLD rule key is?

Comment: I believe this is the LLD key? system.discovery[SERVICES]

Not too sure if that's what you're asking for but that's the only thing with a value of key that I see attached to the discovery rule

Comment: A-ha. That gives me some idea on what you are using - posted full suggestion as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using custom discovery of the Windows services, probably based on [this solution](https://github.com/jjmartres/Zabbix/blob/master/zbx-templates/zbx-windows/zbx-windows-envmon/zabbix_win_system_discovery.vbs). While this key does not seem to have a built-in filtering, you should be able to filter either by plain regexp, or, more likely, by a [global regexp](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/regular_expressions#global_regular_expressions). Alternatively, you could hack the script itself and amend the hardcoded exceptions.

If using Zabbix filtering, you should first create a global regexp that negates the things you want to exclude (like the ones starting with `CDP_` and `Service_`), then use that global regexp in the LLD rule filtering as [outlined in the LLD documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery).

If you would like to hack the script, look for the `SET EXCEPTIONS` section and add your own exceptions. Keep in mind that you will have to deploy your modified version to all the affected boxes - the Zabbix filtering above will be less involved in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for your help Richlv! I was able to add a regular expression to the LLD and it has now successfully started filtering out unwanted services.

For anyone who might run into this same issue the regexp I used was

^/(?!CDP*|Svc*)